# ajax success hangs browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

on input change triggered an ajax call and  on success we modifying 80% content on the page.

2 to 3 requests responses are fine and then the browser is hanging until the success function

update the data.

```
var options = {
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function ()
            {

                $("#main_page :input").attr("disabled","disabled");
            },
            success: updatePage

        };
    form.ajaxSubmit(options);
```

and the success function is

```
updatePage: function(data)
{
    if(data.isEmptyDiv)
    {   
        $('#Messages').html(data.gMessagesHtml);    
        $('.options').remove();
        $('table').remove();
        $('.offers').remove();
        $('.code').remove();
        $('.totals').remove();
        $('.summary').append(data.Html);
        $('.summary').addClass('empty');
        $('.summary').addClass('empty');
    }
    else
        {
            $('#Messages').html(data.MessagesHtml);
            $('table').replaceWith(data.Items);
            $('table').find('.test input[type="number"]').ESO_number_input();
    bindAll();
            $('.offers').html(data.offers);
            $('.code').html(data.code);
            $('.totals').html(data.Totals);
            if(  $('.offers .image').html() != ''){$('div.item_container_holder').hide();}else{$('div.item_container_holder').show();}
        }
    if (!data.Eligible) {
        $('#ButtonTop').removeClass('major');
        $('#ButtonBottom').removeClass('major');
        $('#ButtonTop').addClass('minor');
        $('#ButtonBottom').addClass('minor');
        $('#ButtonTop').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#ButtonBottom').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#ButtonTop').removeClass('minor');
        $('#ButtonBottom').removeClass('minor');
        $('#ButtonTop').addClass('major');
        $('#ButtonBottom').addClass('major');
        $('#ButtonTop').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#tButtonBottom').removeAttr('disabled');
    }


},
```

2,3 ajax requests are working fine. after that the browser hangs for sometime it's happening for all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas.

What does the function

```
bindAll();
```

do? are you binding the same event multiple times and causing some kind of loop?
maybe you need to unbind first or bind in such a way that calling it multiple times applies the binding once?

Is

```
data.Items
```

in

```
$('table').replaceWith(data.Items);
```

really a rendered html table? Do you have more than one table on the page? if so you should probably reference it by ID.

Comment: bindall() is binding only once. I have only one table in the page.I observed that  data.items has large amount of data and this causing browser to hang